# Is SQL Server 2016 Report Builder compatible with SQL Servers 2008 and 2012?

Tags: sql-server, reporting, reportbuilder, ssrs-2016

I'm wondering if I can use the 2016 version of Report Builder with 2008 and 2012 SQL Servers or, if I have to download the three corresponding Report Builders separately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use 2008 and/or 2012 databases as your data sources. I have gone the other way too from SSRS 2005 to using 2008/2012 as data sources.

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer.